# Paging in Datastax Cassandra ODBC driver

Tags: r, cassandra, odbc, datastax, powerbi

I installed Datastax Cassandra ODBC driver and configured it with enable Paging option with 10000 records. When I fetched more than 10000 rows from RStudio using ODBC driver, always the RStudio Session is aborted without showing any error. When I fetched more than 10000 rows from Power BI using ODBC driver, always it is giving error *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt*.

So, I concluded that there is a problem with Datastax Cassndra ODBC Driver. Whether I missed any other Configurations? How to rectify this problem?

Comment: Which version of the ODBC driver are you using, on which platform, and which bitness? Have you tried enabling logging within the driver, and if so, would you be able to copy the last 10-20 lines of the log here?

Comment: I'm using ODBC driver 2.0.17 Version in Windows 32-bit system. and the log is->       Jun 14 11:58:41 INFO  1436 Driver::LogVersions: SDK Version: 09.03.09.1009
Jun 14 11:58:41 INFO  1436 Driver::LogVersions: DSII Version: 1.0.1.1002
Jun 14 11:58:41 ERROR 1436 Connection::SQLGetInfoW: [DataStax][ODBC] (11180) SQLGetInfo property not found: 10025
Jun 14 11:58:41 ERROR 1436 Statement::ExecuteCatalogFunction: [DataStax][CassandraODBC] (40) Unsupported Cassandra type: SimpleDateType.

Comment: The first error can be safely ignore, the second one is a problematic one. Do you have a custom type called SimpleDateType? Additionally, could you update your post with the last 10-20 lines when logging is set to LOG_TRACE so we get all the rest of the information?

Comment: I have CQL date type in my Table Schema. Currently Date type is not supported in ODBC driver. So, I'm not querying date type column in my Query. Actually the error here occured when the ODBC driver requests the table Schema from Cassandra Server. So, it is not at all the Problem for the Paging.

Comment: As before, are you able to supply the last 10-20 lines of the logging when logging is set to LOG_TRACE?